# Error running using web.py on Google App Engine - application instance has no __call__ method

Tags: google-app-engine, web.py

I've been trying to use web.py to run a simple web app on Google App Engine but have been running into some pretty basic errors. I've searched over the site and haven't found anything to address my issue. Here is the outline of the code I'm trying to run:

```
import web

urls = (
    "/","Index"
)

app = web.application(urls,globals())
render = web.template.render('pages/', base="layout")

class Index:
    def GET(self):
        #code...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.cgirun()
```

and this is the app.yaml code:

```
application: #appname
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: home.app
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

But then I get this in the log:

```
2013-08-22 06:11:13 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program     Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', 'C:\\.....\\root\\home-gae']"
INFO     2013-08-22 06:11:16,956 devappserver2.py:557] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2013-08-22 06:11:16,976 api_server.py:317] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-08-22 06:11:17,006 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:64510
INFO     2013-08-22 06:11:17,013 dispatcher.py:164] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-08-22 06:11:17,019 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2013-08-22 10:11:24,303 wsgi.py:235] 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 223, in Handle

    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)

AttributeError: application instance has no __call__ method

INFO     2013-08-22 06:11:24,313 module.py:593] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

The AttributeError is confusing me because there does appear to be a call method in web/application module. Any ideas? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to work it out.

```
import web

urls = (
    "/.*", "hello"
)

application = web.application(urls, globals())
#app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        return "HelloWorld"

#app = app.gaerun()
#app.cgirun()
app = application.wsgifunc()
```

using "app = application.wsgifunc() ", then the code would work well.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a little problem with your app.yaml. You need to put your static handler before the catch-all handler:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: home.app
```

Otherwise, you will not be able to serve static files.

To fix your issue with the website not loading, it looks like the development server is trying to treat your CGI app as a WSGI app. Try to fit you `home.py` file to [the official example for web.py on GAE](http://webpy.org/cookbook/google_app_engine). That is, get rid of the `if __name__ == "__main__:"` part and simply replace it with:

```
app = app.gaerun()
```